# Asus Nexus 7 Tethering and Wifi HotSpot not available

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-7, wifi-hotspot

Using my ASUS Google Nexus 7, I was trying to make it as Portable Wifi Hotspot. But when I opened my settings --> Wireless&Networks there is option for Tethering and Portable Hotspot. I tried [this link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.core.technology.wifi.hotspot&hl=en). Its an app in Play store to enable Wifi Hotspot. Can someone help me to make this work?

SPECIFICATIONS:

Model Number - Nexus 7
 Android Version - 4.2.2
 Build Number - JDQ39

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have the version that includes a GSM modem.

I guess you want to set up an ad-hoc local wifi network?

The non-GSM variants don't offer tethering options because there's obviously no point in tethering when the device lacks the functionality for a GSM mobile data connection. Alas, some rarer use cases like *set up a local wifi accesspoint without internet access* or *USB-tethering the wifi connection* are also not possible then. Only rooted devices or 3rd party firmwares like CyanogenMod offers this.